# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column c.relispartition does not exist

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, exception

*USING: MacbookAir M1 (2020), MacOs Monterey(12.2.1), Python (3.10.2), Django (4.0.2), PostgreSQL (14.2)*

I started a simple django app and when i'm trying to connect my db (postgresql) i get this error

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 83, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column c.relispartition does not exist
LINE 3:             CASE WHEN c.relispartition THEN 'p' WHEN c.relki...
```

here is my settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
                "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
                'OPTIONS': {
                    'options': '-c search_path=prg'
                    },
                "NAME": "******",
                "USER": "******",
                "PASSWORD": "******",
                "HOST": "**.***.***.***",
                "PORT": "5432"
         }
}
```

Never had problems with other db postgres. Have you ever seen something like this?

Comment: `pg_class.relispartition` was introduced in Postgres 10 - so it's highly likely you are connecting to an older version even though you think you are using Postgres 14.

Comment: hi @francesco .. were you able to figure out the reason for the error? I am facing the same error with Django 4.0.4 and Postgres 14.3.2 on Github actions. It works without an error locally.

Answer (score 6):

Downgrading Django to version 3.2 provides a fix for this, however, I've raised a ticket with the Django team for this as it seems peculiar to the current version of Django (4.0).

Comment: According to the docs, Django 4.0 support for PostgreSQL 9.6 ends in November 2021. Django 4.0 supports PostgreSQL 10 and higher. [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#dropped-support-for-postgresql-9-6)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this porblem upgrade your database or django version